# Can't retrieve claims principal in .net core 3.1 web app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

I've been trying to set up the authentication/authorization and claims on my .net core web api (v3.1), but I'm getting a null when trying to access the User from my controller.

Here are the bits in my startup class which concern configuring the auth/claims etc..

```
          // Add Jwt Authentication
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); // => remove default claims
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                //Set default Authentication Schema as Bearer
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
                           JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme =
                           JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme =
                           JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters =
                       new TokenValidationParameters
                       {
                           ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                           ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                           IssuerSigningKey =
                        new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"])),
                           ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
                       };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("User", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User");
                });
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin");
                });
            });          // Add Jwt Authentication
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); // => remove default claims
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                //Set default Authentication Schema as Bearer
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
                           JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme =
                           JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme =
                           JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters =
                       new TokenValidationParameters
                       {
                           ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                           ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                           IssuerSigningKey =
                        new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"])),
                           ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
                       };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("User", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User");
                });
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin");
                });
            });
```

And here is my UserController class - I've removed some of the methods for brevity.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<MongoUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<MongoUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<MongoRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _claimsPrincipal;

        //private  MongoUser _signedInUser;

        public UserController(UserManager<MongoUser> userManager, SignInManager<MongoUser> signInManager, RoleManager<MongoRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _claimsPrincipal = this.User;
        }

        // GET api/user/userdata
        [Authorize(Policy = "User")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UserData()
        {
            var test = this.User;
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_claimsPrincipal);
            var userData = new UserDataResponse
            {
                UserName = user.UserName,
            };
            return Ok(userData);
        }

        // POST api/user/register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegisterEntity model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string key = this._configuration.GetSection("JwtKey").Value;
                var user = new MongoUser(model.UserName);
                //user.Roles = model.Roles;
                user.Email = model.Email;

                if (!_roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("User").Result)
                {
                    MongoRole role = new MongoRole();
                    role.Name = "User";
                    IdentityResult roleResult = _roleManager.
                    CreateAsync(role).Result;
                }

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                var issuer = this._configuration.GetSection("JwtIssuer").Value;
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    //claims
                    var claimList = new List<Claim>();
                    claimList.Add(new Claim("username", model.UserName));
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);

                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, //Issure    
                                                        issuer,  //Audience    
                                                        claimList,
                                                        expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
                                                        signingCredentials: credentials);
                    //AuthenticationHelper.GenerateJwtToken(model.Email, user, _configuration);

                    var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

                    var rootData = new SignUpResponse(encodedJwt, user.UserName);
                    _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User").Wait();
                    return Created("api/authentication/register", rootData);
                }
                return Ok(string.Join(",", result.Errors?.Select(error => error.Description)));
            }
            string errorMessage = string.Join(", ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
            return BadRequest(errorMessage ?? "Bad Request");
        }


        // POST api/user/login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginEntity model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    string key = this._configuration.GetSection("JwtKey").Value;
                    var appUser = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserName == model.UserName);
                    var issuer = this._configuration.GetSection("JwtIssuer").Value;
                    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser);
                    var claimList = new List<Claim>();
                    foreach (var role in roles)
                    {
                        var roleClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role);
                        claimList.Add(roleClaim);
                    }
                    claimList.Add(new Claim("username", model.UserName));

                    //var token = AuthenticationHelper.GenerateJwtToken(model.Email, appUser, _configuration);
                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, //Issure    
                                    issuer,  //Audience    
                                    claimList,
                                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
                                    signingCredentials: credentials);

                    var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

                    var rootData = new LoginResponse(encodedJwt, appUser.UserName);
                    return Ok(rootData);
                }
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Bad Credentials");
            }
            string errorMessage = string.Join(", ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
            return BadRequest(errorMessage ?? "Bad Request");
        }
```

When I try to hit the UserData end point, it seems I now have the authentication and authorization working correctly but I don't seem to be able to access any of the claims information. The following line returns a null...

```
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_claimsPrincipal);
```

**update: I've added a getClaims() method to my controller to establish whether the ClaimsPrincipal object is coming through correctly with the the token - I've included here the method and the response in postman**

GetClaims()

```
        // GET api/user/claims
        [Authorize(Policy ="User")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetClaims()
        {
            var strList = new List<string>();
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (null != principal)
            {
                foreach (Claim claim in principal.Claims)
                {
                    strList.Add("CLAIM TYPE: " + claim.Type + "; CLAIM VALUE: " + claim.Value + "</br>");
                }
            }
            return Ok(strList);
        }
```

Response

```
[
    "CLAIM TYPE: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role; CLAIM VALUE: User</br>",
    "CLAIM TYPE: username; CLAIM VALUE: johnmdowds1</br>",
    "CLAIM TYPE: exp; CLAIM VALUE: 1608209277</br>",
    "CLAIM TYPE: iss; CLAIM VALUE: EzGig</br>",
    "CLAIM TYPE: aud; CLAIM VALUE: EzGig</br>"
]
```

Comment: What is the Response String and the Status.  The response status is normally 200 OK for a good response and a 400/500 for an error.

Comment: 500 internal server error - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'principal')

Comment: Authentication is passing.  If it failed you would not get any response.  The error is self explanatory.   You request needs a parameter called "principal".  Check the documentation and see if the principal is a header in the request or a parameter in the URL like "https://myURL.com?principal=123".

Comment: I dont think the claims principal is supposed to be passed as a param - I think it may be something that is retrieved using the token. I've included an update to my original post which shows a method I've just wrote to get the claims and this seems to work. I've not passed any additional parameters to this method so that information must be being retrieved from the token.

Comment: So everything is working?  You added the principal to the GET Request which seems to work.

Comment: no, the user manager is still returning a null which is causing an error when I use    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_claimsPrincipal);

Comment: The response you posted looks garbled.  It looks like html but the open/close tags are not balaced.  You have a lot of </br> tags but no openinging tags.